# JAVA - HELP adding comparable interface and arrays into my class

Tags: java, arrays, string, comparable, compareto

I got a lab assignment dealing with arrays, sorting them and adding comparable interface to my two classes. I have to modify a Customer class so it implements a comparable interface. Then I have to sort an array of objects created by this class.

These are the steps outlined by my worksheet:

1. open the customer and SortedCustomersApp java files (see below):

   public class Customer

   ```
   {

   private String email;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;

   public Customer(String email, String firstName, String lastName)
   {
       this.email = email;
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   public void setEmail(String email)
   {
       this.email = email;
   }

   public String getEmail()
   {
       return email;
   }

   public void setFirstName(String firstName)
   {
       this.firstName = firstName;
   }

   public String getFirstName()
   {
       return firstName;
   }

   public void setLastName(String lastName)
   {
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   public String getLastName()
   {
       return lastName;
   }
   }
   ```

This is the sorted customers app:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortedCustomersApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

2. add code to the customer class to implement the comparable interface. The compareTo method you create should compare the email field of the current customer with the email field of another customer. To do that you cant use the < or > operators because the email field is a string. Instead, use the compareToIgnoreCase method of the string class. This method compares the string it's executed on with the string that's passed to it as an argument. If the first string is less than the 2nd string, this methods returns a negative integer. if the first string is greater than the second string, it returns a positive integer. And if the 2 strings are equal, it returns 0.

3.Add code to the SortedCustomersApp class that creates an array of Customer objects that can hold 3 elements, and create and assign Customer objects to those elements. Be sure that the email values you assign to the objects aren't in alphabetical order. Sort the array.

4. code a "for each" loop that prints the email, firstName, and lastName fields of each Customer object on a separate line.
5. compile and test the program

This program needs to have user input for email, firstName, and lastName but when I tried adding user input to the customer app I got errors saying I cant convert a string to scanner type, but the user inputs need to be a string so that's also a problem.

Answer (score 1):

you implement Comaprable in order to define for `Collections.sort()` what criteria you use compare instances.For example if I was to compare students by their grades:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>{

    int age;
    int grade;


    //this method is used in Collections.sort() to determine what is bigger
    //for me its grades that matter so that's what I do in  code
    @override
    compareTo(Student other){

     if(this.grade>other.grade){

        return 1;   
     }else if(grade<other.grade){

       return -1;
      }

       return 0;
    }



}
```

then you just create an ArrayList students for example and call

```
Collections.sort(students)
```

EDIT: to answer you question in comments. If you use a `Collection` like `ArrayList` you would call `Collections.sort()` , if you use a regular array, then `Arrays.sort()`. In both cases the Objects to be sorted need to implement `Comparable` just like I showed you.

Comment: First, thanks for your input! Much appreciated! Second, my book hadn't mentioned anything about collections.sort , just the methods of the array class including Arrays.sort. Are they interchangeable terms? Also, your example is well written but Im more having trouble creating a compareTo method that uses strings instead of numerical values.

Comment: Also how do you intend to compare 2 customers? lexicographically?

Comment: Well my professor was pretty vague as to what she wanted, I suppose lexicographically since all she said was that the end results could be a negative, positive number or a 0 if both email strings are the same. I was thinking of doing something like this: (this.email.compareToIgnoreCase(other.email)>0)    or   (this.email.compareToIgnoreCase(other.email<0) and then have an     else{System.out.println("both emails are the same")     that way it could could compare both emails and give an appropriate response based on the result of the comparison. I dont think I have to do that though...

Comment: My other issue is that I'm only supposed to add code to the java files already given to me above, and not change the code already there(the customer class specifically). I'm trying to add user input, but every time I write code in the main sortedCustomersApp that creates customer objects and refer to its set methods put a scanner object in the parenthesis of the referenced method to add user input but I always get the error "cant convert string to scanner".

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two String's lexicographically calling compareTo method on String object, code looks like this

```
public class Customer implements Comparable<Customer>{

private String email;

public Customer(String email) {
    this.email = email;

}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}


@Override
public int compareTo(Customer otherCustomer) {
    return this.email.compareToIgnoreCase(otherCustomer.email);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Customer{" +
            "email='" + email + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

You can sort list of objects using Collections.sort method

```
 List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(new Customer("abc@bc.com"));
    list.add(new Customer("des@bc.com"));
    list.add(new Customer("bbc@bc.com"));
    list.add(new Customer("aec@bc.com"));
    Collections.sort(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

modified customer class

```
public class Customer implements Comparable<Customer>{
    :
    public int compareTo(Object obj)
    {
        Customer cus = (Customer) obj;
        // write your comparison code here
        // return 1, 0, or -1 on the basis of your requirement

    }    
    :
}
```

Then perform

```
Collection.sort(customerList);
```

in main method to sort the data.

There is two ways to take String as an input from user: 
1) Buffered Reader

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 String email = reader.readLine(); // email, firstname etc.
```

2) Scanner Class

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String email = input.next();
```

Now create an Customer object and add setter method to set the value.